# How to split rows with Select Statement

Tags: sql, select, split, row, addition

I'd like to make a SELECT from this Table:

[image]

Which shows me this result:

[image]

Is this possible in any way?

Answer (score 0):

Use UNION ALL

```
select * from
(select objectNr, BW, '' color
union all
select objectNr, '' BW, color)
where BW != '' or color != ''
order by objectNr, color
```